# How do I get a disabled ToolStripButton to paint its image in colour?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, toolstripbutton

We have a button which allows users to 'lock' a form.  Users are not permitted to 'unlock' the form, so when pressed, we want the button to be disabled, so that the user receives appropriate visual feedback.

However, the customer reports that the greyed 'lock' icon suggests to them that the form is not locked, so we would like to display the button in a pressed state, but with the icon in colour, even though the button is disabled.

How do we do that, with the absolute minimum amount of overridden painting?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `ToolStripButton Image` as `BackgroundImage`
and then set the `DiplayStyle` to `None`.

The picture should stay in colour no matter what's the button `Enabled` value.

Comment: That doesn't quite work - for some reason the button doesn't respect ImageLayout.Center as a BackgroundImageLayout, so the image gets drawn in the top left corner.

Comment: You're right but if your picture has good ratio, you can use 'BackgroundImageLayout.Stretch' instead.

Comment: Hum ok I've just tried and the background image seems to disappear once the button become checked so it's still not a good answer sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Actually I disagree with the approach.  Your customer might have a valid point, but I don't think they have the correct suggestion for the fix.  You should look into other ways to make the form appear "locked".  Changing borders or font colours, having a big padlock  icon appear or change from open to closed etc.  Buttons look a certain way because that's what users expect.  If you have a disabled button that looks like it might be enabled, that's going to confuse users who might not then understand why they can't click it.

Comment: I agree with you, but they're the ones who're paying.

Answer (score 1):

I was in this case few weeks ago and this question doesn't have an answer, so this is my solution 4 years later :

I'm using this solution to repaint the ToolStripButton in many cases : disabled, checked, selected

1. override OnPaint event or change renderer of your ToolStrip
2. draw your image without grey filter with this method, just set the image of the button and image's position on your button : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/chas0s9c(v=vs.110).aspx

Two good examples who helped me :

- http://tutorials.csharp-online.net/Tool,_Menu,_and_Status_Strips%E2%80%94Customizing_a_Renderer
- http://jskiles1.wordpress.com/2009/08/22/33/)

ToolStrip class :

```
ToolStrip ts = new ToolStrip();
//[...]
ts.RenderMode = ToolStripRenderMode.Professional; //Professional is just an example
ts.Renderer = new CustomRenderer();
```

CustomRenderer class :

```
public class CustomRenderer: ToolStripProfessionalRenderer
{
    protected override void OnRenderButtonBackground(ToolStripItemRenderEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!e.Item.Enabled) //in this case you will just have the image in your button, you need to add text etc in this if
        {
             //to draw the image
             Graphics g = e.Graphics;
             g.DrawImageUnscaled(e.Item.Image, new Point(2, 2)); //you need to specify the correct position
        }
        else //other cases
            base.OnRenderButtonBackground(e);
     }
}
```

The problem is to know the correct position of all elements in your ToolStripButton , that's why I drawn the ToolStripButton in every cases

Answer (score 0):

Another way: don't set the `button.Enabled = false` at all. Just set the `button.Checked = true` or `false` and when someone clicks on the button test for the `Checked` state and do whatever you do. The button will then function as you want and stay colored too.

Comment: Good point, but he did say that users can't unlock the form though, so that's not really what he's after.

Comment: Yeah, if I leave button.Enabled as true, the user still gets visual feedback when they hover over the button, so it looks like they can click.